# ¿Como centrar un elemento dentro de un contenedor que a su vez tiene un elemento flotante?, el elemento flotante define el alto final del contenedor

Tags: css, css3

Quisiera que el elemento que **tiene el h1 y los párrafos** este centrado en el header, ese header tiene un flotante, Por eso para centrar el elemento antes mencionado lo que he intentado fue, darle un `height: 100%;` al
`<div class="container></div>` que es padre del elemento que tiene los **parrafos y el h1**, luego pensaba hacerlo flex-container y así centrar.

Pero no funciono el dar `height: 100%`, supongo que es porque si bien es cierto que el header esta conteniendo al elemento flotante gracias a `display: flow-root`, al dar un alto en porcentajes a sus hijos ese porcentaje no cuenta con el alto adicional que el elemento flotante puede agregar al elemento header.

Estoy consciente que no siempre la imagen flotante va a hacer que el header sea mas alto, porque la imagen puede ser bastante pequeña para eso.

Otra cosa que intente es `position: absolute`, luego `top: 0, bottom: 0` pero el espacio del `div class="container">` no se tiene en cuenta para hacer crecer al header, y debido a eso termina desbordándose en algún punto.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda

Ese layout pienso mantenerlo en pantallas cuyo ancho tiene como mínimo `994px`

## código

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

/*Imagen flotando a la derecha, debido a su contenedor con float: right*/
img{
  width: 100%;
}

.float{
  float: right;
  width: 45vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

.desc{
  padding-top: 12%;
  padding-bottom: 12%;
}

.desc > div{
 width: 50%;
}

.header{
  display: flow-root;
  background-image: url("http://demo.themeies.com/leospa/images/leaf.png");
  background-size: 12%;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!--Header con display: flow-root para contener el elemento flotante--!-->
<header class="header">
 
 <!--Imagen flotante a la derecha---!-->
  <div class="float">
    <img src="http://demo.themeies.com/leospa/images/spa.png">
  </div> 
  
   <!--El contenido de este container quiero centrarlo con respecto al header---!-->
  <div class="container">
     
        <div class="desc">
          <div>
            <h1 class="header__headingPage">
                Beauty and success starts here. It's Overwhelming this layout
            </h1>
            <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia saepe omnis consectetur. Perferendis in, dolorem ex rerum quo reprehenderit sit, eveniet ducimus illum distinctio optio cum magni voluptate, enim eum.
          </p>
         </div>
      </div>    
    
  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas `floats` se descontrola tu layout.

Pará que el contenedor `float` no sea más pequeño que su hijo, utiliza `overflow: hidden`.

Pará centrar el elemento dentro de un box `float` puedes utilizar foexbox:  `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center` en el padre. O si no, utilizar el position: `position: absolute; left, top, right, bottom: 0; margin: auto` así centraría el contenido fácilmente.

Espero que sea esta la solución a tu problema, porque la verdad no entendí muy bien.